# Fixed points of a group action on tree

Tags: group-theory, graph-theory, trees, geometric-group-theory, combinatorial-group-theory

Suppose a group $H$ acts on a tree $T$, and this action fixes a point. Let $T_1$ be an $H$ invariant subtree of $T$. How do I show that $H$ fixes a point in $T_1$?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Do you want to show that $H$ fixes $T_1$? Didn't you just say that $T_1$ is a $H$-invariant subtree? So, it remains fixed by $H$ by definition?

Comment: @stressedout Maybe think *stable* instead of *fixed*.

Comment: @MikePierce OK. So, $H$ might permute the elements of $T_1$? But we want to prove that $H$ actually fixes them?

Comment: I think we need the assumption that $G$ is finite — take the infinite, two-ended path, and add a new vertex attached to every vertex on the path. Then $\mathbb{Z}$ acts on the graph by just sliding the path, and it fixes the new vertex. The path is a stable subtree that fixes no point on the subtree.

Comment: @Santana How is the n-star a counter example? Every subtree of it has fixed point (that is the center).

Comment: @SantanaAfton $T$ is meant to be a tree otherwise it definitely does not hold (as your example shows).

Comment: As the question is now, the $n$-star isn’t a counterexample and the infinite path construction is. The $n$-star is a counterexample to the claim “$H$ fixes all stable subtrees if it has a fixed point.” I’ve edited the question to reflect that $T$ also needs to be a tree, so the path construction is no longer a counterexample.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $a\in T$ be the given point such that $a\cdot h=a$ for all $h\in H$. Let $x\in T_1$ such that $d(x, a)$ is minimal.

**Lemma.** The point $x$ is fixed by $H$.

*Sketch proof.* You first need to prove that if $y\in T_1$ is such that $d(x, a)=d(y, a)$ then $x=y$. To see this, you prove that there is a path $p$ from $x$ to $y$ contained in $T_1$, and hence there is a cycle which connecting the three points $x$, $a$ and $y$, a contradiction as $T$ is a tree. You need to use the minimality of $d(x, a)$ lots.

Now, as $H$ acts on $T$ by isometries, distance is preserved. Hence, for all $h\in H$ we have that $d(x\cdot h, a)=d(x, a)$. It follows from the above paragraph that $x\cdot h=x$ for all $h\in H$, as required.

Comment: Could you explain what $H$ acts on $T$ by isometries means please? I didn't understand the last paragraph.

Comment: @stressedout I just mean it preserves distance. The action of $H$ on $T$ is taking edges to edges and vertices to vertices, so it preserves distance.